# Issue with MySQL/phpmyadmin configuration

Tags: php, mysql

When I try to login to mysql through phpmyadmin I get the following errors:

```
#2002 - No such file or directory<br />The server is not responding (or the local server's socket is not correctly configured).



Connection for controluser as defined in your configuration failed.
```

I run the following command and find that mysql is not using any port:

```
sudo netstat -tlpn | grep mysql
```

When I restart the mysql service and then check the port again it shows

```
tcp6       0      0 :::3306                 :::*                    LISTEN      3808/mysqld
```

and there is no more error in phpmyadmin and I can continue working with mysql.

To work, I have to restart the mysql service everytime I start my system. Please help me with the error and tell me how to get rid of it.

This is my mysql version `mysql  Ver 14.14 Distrib 5.6.16` and this is my php version `PHP Version 5.6.36-1`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to ensure mysql is running on boot then here's how you'd enable it in via the startup service.

**Ubuntu 16+**

`sudo systemctl enable mysql`

**Ubuntu 14**

`sudo update-rc.d mysql defaults`

Comment: Thank you mate, that worked! :)
But was this the cleanest solution possible? I thought there was some error with any of the configuration files.

Comment: Accepting this answer as this worked for me and there was no activity for a long time.. Thank you for the solution again..